# How do i write BDD scenarios in fitnesse with .Net like Given when then format using Fitsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, bdd, fitnesse, fitsharp

We need to write scenarios in Fitnesse in Given When Then (Gherkin)
Is there any way to do this? like in java **GivWenZen**

we are using fitnesse in .Net 4.0 using Fitsharp.

scenario:
Existing Fitnesse table-

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {fit}
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -r fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer %p}
!define TEST_RUNNER {D:\API_TC_Setup\Fitnesse\Runner.exe}


!path D:\API_TC_Setup\FitnesseBDDDemo\FitnesseBDDDemo\bin\Debug\FitnesseBDDDemo.dll

|configure|processor|add operator|findmemberpattern|

!|import |
| FitnesseBDDDemo|
|Class1|
|Given User should login|
|When User place an Order|
|Then Order should present in market|
```

Here is the code for above scenario

```
namespace FitnesseBDDDemo
   {
   public class Class1
      {
      [MemberPattern ( "Given User should login" )]
      public void LoginUser1( )
         {
         Console.WriteLine ( "Executing loggin-" );
         }
      //When User place an Order
      [MemberPattern ( "When User place an Order" )]
      public void PlaceOrder( )
         {
         Console.WriteLine ( " Order placing-" );
         }
      //Then Order should present in market
      [MemberPattern ( "Then Order should present in market" )]
      public void OrderInMarket( )
         {
         Console.WriteLine ( "Order in market-" );
         }
      }
   }
```

Error -

No error my scenario is Ignored while executing Please look this snap

[FitnesseResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhmfR.png)

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Can you give an example of a scenario you'd like to write?  Then maybe I can show you how to do it.

Comment: thanks mike I update question please check

Comment: Hey, downvoters - this is a perfectly valid question - if you don't understand the technology being asked about, don't downvote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the FindMemberPattern operator
See: http://fitsharp.github.io/Fit/FindMemberPatternOperator.html

Your test could be:

(These lines could go on an ancestor page)

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {fit}
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -r fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer %p}
```

(This next line could go on a SetUp page)

```
|configure|processor|add operator|findmemberpattern|

|Place Order|
|Given User user1 should login|
|When Placing Bid Order|
|Then Order Available In Market|
```

Your code would contain:

```
[MemberPattern("Given User (.*) should login")]
public bool LoginUser(string user) { ... }

[MemberPattern("When Placing (.*) Order")]
public bool PlacingOrder(string side) { ... }

[MemberPattern("Then Order Available In Market")]
public bool OrderAvailableInMarket() { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks mike do i need to do any configuration for that? i m facing   error "Could not find class configure" at -- **|configure|processor|add operator|findmemberpattern|**

Comment: Thanks Mike i am adding  this lines but facing error -**Could not complete testing: java.lang.InterruptedException: FitClient was killed** can you please help I have updated question plz check fitnesse config code

Comment: Did you take out the old TEST_SYSTEM and COMMAND_PATTERN defines?  In your updated question, you still have the Slim definitions.  These should be replaced by the ones in my answer.

Comment: Again i update my question please look in that i am facing new issue look in to [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KhmfR.png) my scenario is ignored This is my Test result you can look firdt line in result test pages : 1 Ignored

Comment: Just put a blank line between | FitnesseBDDDemo| and |Class1|.  All your test lines are being treated as part of the Import table.

Comment: Thank you very much mike its working..thanks a lot for help

Comment: Is any way to generate graphical html  reports of fitnesse Test  ?

Comment: I don't know how to generate a graphical report, but ask this as a separate question - someone else may have an answer